# DRF TimeZoneField: not JSON serializable error

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, zoneinfo

I have django model:

```
from django.db import models
from timezone_field import TimeZoneField

class Client(models.Model):
    time_zone = TimeZoneField(choices_display='WITH_GMT_OFFSET')
```

And APIView for this model:

```
class ClientAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request, pk: int, format=None) -> Response:

        client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=pk)
        client_serializer = ClientListSerializer(client)
        return Response(client_serializer.data)
```

I get an error from GET request: `TypeError: Object of type ZoneInfo is not JSON serializable`

Serializer code:

```
class ClientListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'time_zone')
```

How fix code of Model, Serializer or View (I don't know what exactly) so that instead of ZoneInfo there is just a string.

UPDATE: if change serializer:

```
class ClientListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time_zone = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
```

GET request will be work, but POST request give me error, if send invalid string for time zone. For example `{"time_zone": "invalid string"}`
Result: `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["Invalid timezone 'invalid string'"]`

My POST method code:

```
    def post(self, request: Request, format=None) -> Response:
        client_serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not client_serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(client_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        client_serializer.save()
        return Response('client was created successfully', status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

---

SOLVED

Maybe this is not the best solution, but now requests work correctly after modify `serializer`:

```
import pytz
from rest_framework import serializers


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time_zone = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=pytz.all_timezones)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'time_zone')
```

If you know better solution, share with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Django 4.0+**

Django 4.0 makes `zoneinfo` the default implementation. Support for `pytz` is now deprecated and will be removed in Django 5.0.

```
from zoneinfo import available_timezones

from rest_framework import serializers


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time_zone = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=available_timezones())

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['id', 'time_zone', ]
```